# How to Modify wordpress plugin variable value

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

**myCred** is a plugin to **WordPress** that allows you to easily create **Point Balances** and set up the steps users take to earn them.

Here are the links to their open source plugin:

Github: https://github.com/wp-plugins/mycred

myCred Site: https://mycred.me/

Wordpress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/mycred/

Ready! here it is: I can't find a solution how to add my own `$amount` to the `$current_balance` to get the `$new_balance`?

I've tried something like this already with no luck:

```
add_filter('filter_update_users_balance', 'add_my_own_amount');

function add_my_own_amount($amount){
return 10;
}
```

Let's have a look at **mycred-functions.php** file.

first of all, it **gets users balances** like this : (I'm not sure if it's necessary to read in order to solve my problem or not, I recommend to skip it for now:))

```
     /**
      * Get users balance

     * Returns the users balance unformated.
     *
     * @param $user_id (int), required user id
     * @param $type (string), optional cred type to check for
     * @returns zero if user id is not set or if no creds were found, else returns amount
     * @since 0.1
     * @version 1.4.1
     */
public function get_users_balance( $user_id = NULL, $type = NULL ) {

    if ( $user_id === NULL ) return $this->zero();

    // Type
    $point_types = mycred_get_types();
    if ( $type === NULL || ! array_key_exists( $type, $point_types ) ) $type = $this->get_cred_id();

    $balance = mycred_get_user_meta( $user_id, $type, '', true );
    if ( $balance == '' ) $balance = $this->zero();

    // Let others play
    $balance = apply_filters( 'mycred_get_users_cred', $balance, $this, $user_id, $type );

    return $this->number( $balance );

}
    // Replaces
    public function get_users_cred( $user_id = NULL, $type = NULL ) {

        return $this->get_users_balance( $user_id, $type );

    }
```

after that it **Updates users balances** like this :

here we have this line of code `$new_balance = $current_balance+$amount;` that shows us how the plugin returns new balances of the users. and in the very bottom of the code, it does `return $this->number( $new_balance );` so, we can set the **users balance** based on `$new_balance` value later.

```
/**
         * Update users balance
         * Returns the updated balance of the given user.
         *
         * @param $user_id (int), required user id
         * @param $amount (int|float), amount to add/deduct from users balance. This value must be pre-formated.
         * @param $type (string), optional point type key to adjust instead of the current one.
         * @returns the new balance.
         * @since 0.1
         * @version 1.4.2
         */
        public function update_users_balance( $user_id = NULL, $amount = NULL, $type = NULL ) {

            // Minimum Requirements: User id and amount can not be null
            if ( $user_id === NULL || $amount === NULL ) return $amount;

            // Type
            $point_types = mycred_get_types();
            if ( $type === NULL || ! array_key_exists( $type, $point_types ) ) $type = $this->get_cred_id();

            // Enforce max
            if ( $this->max() > $this->zero() && $amount > $this->max() ) {

                $_amount = $amount;
                $amount  = $this->number( $this->max() );

                do_action( 'mycred_max_enforced', $user_id, $_amount, $this->max() );

            }

            // Adjust creds
            $current_balance = $this->get_users_balance( $user_id, $type );
            $new_balance     = $current_balance+$amount;

            // Update creds
            mycred_update_user_meta( $user_id, $type, '', $new_balance );

            // Update total creds
            $total = mycred_query_users_total( $user_id, $type );
            mycred_update_user_meta( $user_id, $type, '_total', $total );

            // Clear caches
            mycred_delete_option( 'mycred-cache-total-' . $type );

            // Let others play
            do_action( 'mycred_update_user_balance', $user_id, $current_balance, $amount, $type );

            // Return the new balance
            return $this->number( $new_balance );

        }
```

Then it **sets users balances** like this :

```
/**
         * Set users balance
         * Changes a users balance to the amount given.
         *
         * @param $user_id (int), required user id
         * @param $new_balance (int|float), amount to add/deduct from users balance. This value must be pre-formated.
         * @returns (bool) true on success or false on fail.
         * @since 1.7.3
         * @version 1.0.1
         */
        public function set_users_balance( $user_id = NULL, $new_balance = NULL ) {

            // Minimum Requirements: User id and amount can not be null
            if ( $user_id === NULL || $new_balance === NULL ) return false;

            $type        = $this->get_cred_id();
            $new_balance = $this->number( $new_balance );
            $old_balance = $this->get_users_balance( $user_id, $type );

            // Update balance
            mycred_update_user_meta( $user_id, $type, '', $new_balance );

            // Clear caches
            mycred_delete_option( 'mycred-cache-total-' . $type );

            // Let others play
            do_action( 'mycred_set_user_balance', $user_id, $new_balance, $old_balance, $this );

            return true;

        }
```

Finally in **mycred-balances.php** file we have :

```
// Add to the balance
   if ( $method == 'add' )
   $mycred->update_users_balance( $user_id, $balance );

// Change the balance
   else
   $mycred->set_users_balance( $user_id, $balance );
```

I've spent hours and hours to find a solution, **I think I can't find a solution**, so I would really appreciate if you could help me solve this problem.

**Edit :**

I want to increment myCred's `$amount` value with the value of my javascript variable! I want to assign variable of Wordpress plugin (I think it is `$amount`) to value of a javascript variable in order to connecting interactive e-learning courses to the WordPress myCred plugin, that would be amazing gamification experience…!

Let me explain this a bit more:

Using jQuery `post()` method I’m able to Submit data (for example a numeric javascript variable ) to be processed to a specified PHP file in the server. let’s have a look at my code to understand what I want to do with it :

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var speechResult= 10;          
$.ajax({
    url:"https://...Example.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {'speechResult': speechResult},
    success: function(res) {
             console.log(res)
    }
  });
```

And here is the code in my **Example.php**. it just show **speechResult** value in the console (The value that comes from my javascript code!):

```
<?php
    print($_POST['speechResult'])
?>
```

as you can see I have a JavaScript variable named **speechResult**, and I have a **PHP** file named “Example.php”.

By using the code above I can pass **speechResult** value to **Example.php** or any other **PHP** file on the server (**But not PHP files of myCred plugin, because I don't know how to use hooks, filters, actions, etc**).

**If I pass **speechResult** value to `$amount` variable in myCred** then I'll take control of rewading points to users based on what happens in the e-leaning html5 course ...

I want to pass **speechResult** value to assign myCred `$amount` value... in order to incrementing or decrementing **use's total balance point**.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, what you want to achieve. Maybe adding 10 to every balance?

You can use `add_filter` wherever you find `apply_filters` in the code. So here for example:

```
add_filter('mycred_get_users_cred', function($balance, $this, $user_id, $type) {
    return $balance + 10;
});
```

Not sure, if this helps...

Comment: It's in the function 'get_users_balance'